# unsubscribe to upload observable in angular 6 stop upload progress but not actual upload

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

when trying to cancel upload by unsubscribing what actually happen that i unsubscribe to upload progress but that actual upload is not cancelled and keep uploading to the server.
upload.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UploadService } from '../../../services';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-image-upload-item',
  templateUrl: './image-upload-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-upload-item.component.scss']
  })
 export class ImageUploadItemComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() index: any;
  @Output() uploadSuccess: EventEmitter<any>;
  @Output() uploadCanceled: EventEmitter<any>;
  public localimageURL: string;
  public uploadProgress: number;
  public isUploadCompleted: boolean;
  public uploadImageObservable: Subscription;
  public isReadyForUpload: boolean;
   public isUploading: boolean;
   public progressMode: string;
  public readonly unique: string = Math.floor((Math.random() * 
   100)).toString();
   public readonly imagePreviewID = 'imagePreview' + this.unique;


      _file: any;
     @Input() public set file(value: any) {
     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.localimageURL = e.target.result;
    };
     this._file = value;
    reader.readAsDataURL(this._file);
    console.log(this._file);


     }
    constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) {
     this.uploadProgress = 0;
     this.isUploading = false;
     this.localimageURL = '';
      this.isUploadCompleted = false;
      this.uploadSuccess = new EventEmitter<any>();
      this.uploadCanceled = new EventEmitter<any>();
      this.progressMode = 'indeterminate';
       }

     ngOnInit() {
       this.uploadImageToServer(this._file);

      // setTimeout(() => {
      //   console.log('im in set time out unsubscripting', 
        this.uploadImageObservable);
      //    this.uploadImageObservable.forEach(subscription => {
     //     subscription.unsubscribe();
      //   });
   // }, 100);
   }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('component destroyed');
    this.uploadImageObservable.unsubscribe();
    }
    public clearUploadButtonClicked() {
    // if (this.uploadImageObservable !== undefined) {
   //   console.log('image observable is defined');
   //   this.uploadImageObservable.unsubscribe();
   //   console.log(this.uploadImageObservable.closed);
  // }
    // this.uploadImageObservable.unsubscribe();
   this._file = '';
    this.uploadCanceled.emit({ index: this.index, uploaded: false });
  }

   public get showUploadProgress(): boolean {
    return this.uploadProgress !== 0;
   }


   public uploadImageToServer(file) {
     this.isUploading = true;
    const progress = new Subject<number>();
     progress.subscribe(value => {
       this.uploadProgress = value;
     });

   this.uploadImageObservable = this.uploadService.uploadImage(file)
    .subscribe(result => {
      const type = result.type;
      const data = result.data;
      console.log(result);

       if (type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * data.loaded / data.total);
        progress.next(percentDone);
        if (percentDone === 100) {
          this.progressMode = 'indeterminate';
         }
        } else if (type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          if (data) {
            progress.complete();
           this.progressMode = 'determinate';
           this.isReadyForUpload = false;
           this.isUploadCompleted = true;
           this.isUploading = false;
            this.uploadSuccess.emit({ index: this.index, mediaItem: data });
          }

       }
     }, errorEvent => {
     });
  }

   }
```

upload.service.ts

```
  public uploadImage(imageFile: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
     if (imageFile !== undefined) {
       formData.append('image', imageFile, imageFile.name);

      const req = new HttpRequest('POST', environment.uploadImageEndPoint, 
      formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
    });

   return new Observable<any>(observer => {
     this.httpClient.request<any>(req).subscribe(event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
      const responseBody = event.body;
      if (responseBody) {
        this.alertService.success(responseBody.message);
        observer.next({ type: event.type, data: new 
      MediaItem(responseBody.mediaItem) });
      }
    } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
      observer.next({ type: event.type, data: { loaded: event.loaded, total: 
   event.total } });

    } else {
      observer.next(event);
    }
  }, errorEvent => {
    if (errorEvent.status === 400) {
      this.alertService.error(errorEvent.error['image']);
    } else {
      this.alertService.error('Server Error, Please try again later!');
    }
    observer.next(null);
    });
   });
  }
 }
```

how can i cancel upload request properly with observable unsubscribe
note i already tried pipe takeuntil() and nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i found a way as follows

```
public uploadImage(imageFile: File): Observable<any> {
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
if (imageFile !== undefined) {
  formData.append('image', imageFile, imageFile.name);

  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', environment.uploadImageEndPoint, formData, {
    reportProgress: true,
  });

  return this.httpClient.request<any>(req).pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      return res;
    }),
    catchError(errorEvent => {
      if (errorEvent.status === 400) {
        this.alertService.error(errorEvent.error['image']);
      } else {
        this.alertService.error('Server Error, Please try again later!');
        return Observable.throw(errorEvent);
      }
      return Observable.throw(errorEvent);
    }));
}
```

}

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more on this code snippet. What is the idea behind it? How did you found this solution? Are there alternatives?

Comment: from what i understood is that uploading usually have two streams one for the uploading file and one for the upload progress so what pipe is doing is gathering the two streams into one pipe and then we map on this pipe and return the result in one observable so instead of two streams away from each other we have one observable we can subscribe to have the two streams.

Comment: Did this solution work for anyone else? It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is return the result from the pipe function on the http request return observable. Right now you have multiple streams and the component's unsubscribe is only unsubscribing to the observable wrapping the http request observable (not connected).

You'll want to do something like:

```
return this.httpClient.request<any>(req).pipe(
    // use rxjs operators here
);
```

You'll then use rxjs [operators (I've been doing this for a while, but I still highly reference this site)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) to perform any logic needed and reflect things like your errors and upload progress to the component calling the service. On the component side, you'll keep your subscribe/unsubscribe logic.

For instance, you can use the [switchMap operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) to transform what is returning to the component from the http request observable and specify the value to return to the component, and [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) to react to any errors accordingly.

```
return this.httpClient.request<any>(req).pipe(
    switchMap(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            const responseBody = event.body;
            if (responseBody) {
                this.alertService.success(responseBody.message);
                return { type: event.type, data: new MediaItem(responseBody.mediaItem) };
            }
        } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            return { type: event.type, data: { loaded: event.loaded, total: event.total } };
        }
        return event;
    }),
    catchError(errorEvent => {
        if (errorEvent.status === 400) {
            this.alertService.error(errorEvent.error['image']);
        } else {
            this.alertService.error('Server Error, Please try again later!');
        }
        return of(<falsy or error value>);
    }),
);
```

**Alternatively** you could model it a little more after [this example](https://medium.com/@asabya/file-upload-with-progress-bar-user-angular-5-and-nodejs-730852384145) by just returning the http function call from the service to the component and handling things in the subscribe there.

Comment: it gave me this error:  observableInput<{}>'.
      Type 'HttpProgressEvent' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{}>'.
        Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'HttpProgressEvent'.

Comment: Going to need more details than that, what line?

Comment: on     mergeMap(event => {
 line

Comment: Ah, my bad, probably needs switchMap instead (to return a different type of stream)

Comment: will this stay the same :   public uploadImage(imageFile: File): Observable<any> {

Comment: Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
      Property 'then' is missing in type 'HttpSentEvent' but required in type 'PromiseLike<{}>'. [2345]

Comment: The problem in my currentExample is that your code wants to default the return to "event" (in my switchmap). Try removing that

Comment: i will try thnx alot